# Snake game in python, the food does not appear on the screen

Tags: python, class, inheritance, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to create a snake game with Turtle graphics.
The food is a class that inherits the Turtle but when I run the code is does not appear on the screen:

food.py

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random

class Food(Turtle):

    def __int__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("circle")
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(stretch_len=0.5, stetch_wid=0.5)
        self.color("blue")
        random_x = random.randint(-280,280)
        random_y = random.randint(-280, 280)
        self.goto(random_x, random_y)
        print(random_x,random_y)
```

snake.py

```
from turtle import Turtle

STARTING_POSITIONS = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]
MOVE_DISTANCE = 20
UP = 90
DOWN = 270
RIGHT = 0
LEFT = 180


class Snake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.segments = []
        self.create_snake()

    def create_snake(self):
        for position in STARTING_POSITIONS:
            new_segment = Turtle(shape="square")
            new_segment.color("white")
            new_segment.pu()
            new_segment.setpos(position)
            self.segments.append(new_segment)

    def move(self):
        for seg_num in range((len(self.segments) - 1), 0, -1):
            new_x = self.segments[seg_num - 1].xcor()
            new_y = self.segments[seg_num - 1].ycor()
            self.segments[seg_num].goto(new_x, new_y)
        self.segments[0].forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)

    def up(self):
        if self.segments[0].heading() != DOWN:
            self.segments[0].setheading(UP)

    def down(self):
        if self.segments[0].heading() != UP:
            self.segments[0].setheading(DOWN)

    def left(self):
        if self.segments[0].heading() != RIGHT:
            self.segments[0].setheading(LEFT)

    def right(self):
        if self.segments[0].heading() != LEFT:
            self.segments[0].setheading(RIGHT)e
```

main.py

```
from turtle import Screen
from snake import Snake
from food import Food
import time

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600,height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("My Snake Game")
screen.tracer(0)

food = Food()
snake = Snake()


screen.listen()
screen.onkey(snake.up,"Up")
screen.onkey(snake.down, "Down")
screen.onkey(snake.left, "Left")
screen.onkey(snake.right, "Right")

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    snake.move()

screen.exitonclick()
```

`your text`

When I created the food in the main.py file it was created, but when I tried to import it, it does not get created
The screen and the snake are created, the snake get commands from thekeyboard.
I tried running it with Thonny, I saw that the food1 variable was allocated a memory, but when i performed debug and tried to "step into" Food(), it did not go into the class

Comment: In one of your function there is a mistake ```def right(self): if self.segments[0].heading() != LEFT: self.segments[0].setheading(RIGHT)e```
you can see there is letter `e` in the end. remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the actual working code. 
food.py

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random

class Food(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(shape="circle")
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(stretch_len=0.5, stretch_wid=0.5)
        self.color("blue")
        self.move_to_new_location()

    def move_to_new_location(self):
        random_x = random.randint(-280, 280)
        random_y = random.randint(-280, 280)
        self.goto(random_x, random_y)
```

snake.py

```
from turtle import Turtle

STARTING_POSITIONS = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]
MOVE_DISTANCE = 20
UP = 90
DOWN = 270
RIGHT = 0
LEFT = 180


class Snake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.segments = []
        self.create_snake()

    def create_snake(self):
        for position in STARTING_POSITIONS:
            new_segment = Turtle(shape="square")
            new_segment.color("white")
            new_segment.pu()
            new_segment.setpos(position)
            self.segments.append(new_segment)

    def move(self):
        for seg_num in range((len(self.segments) - 1), 0, -1):
            new_x = self.segments[seg_num - 1].xcor()
            new_y = self.segments[seg_num - 1].ycor()
            self.segments[seg_num].goto(new_x, new_y)
        self.segments[0].forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)

    def up(self):
        if self.segments[0].heading() != DOWN:
            self.segments[0].setheading(UP)

    def down(self):
        if self.segments[0].heading() != UP:
            self.segments[0].setheading(DOWN)

    def left(self):
        if self.segments[0].heading() != RIGHT:
            self.segments[0].setheading(LEFT)

    def right(self):
        if self.segments[0].heading() != LEFT:
            self.segments[0].setheading(RIGHT)
```

main.py

```
import time
from turtle import Screen

from food import Food
from snake import Snake


def play_game():
    screen = Screen()
    screen.setup(width=600,height=600)
    screen.bgcolor("black")
    screen.title("My Snake Game")
    screen.tracer(0)

    food = Food()
    screen.addshape("circle", ((-5, -5), (-5, 5), (5, 5), (5, -5)))
    snake = Snake()

    screen.listen()
    screen.onkey(snake.up,"Up")
    screen.onkey(snake.down, "Down")
    screen.onkey(snake.left, "Left")
    screen.onkey(snake.right, "Right")

    game_is_on = True
    while game_is_on:
        screen.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        snake.move()
        if snake.segments[0].distance(food) < 20:
            food.move_to_new_location()
        if snake.segments[0].xcor() > 280 or snake.segments[0].xcor() < -280 or snake.segments[0].ycor() > 280 or snake.segments[0].ycor() < -280:
            game_is_on = False

    screen.exitonclick()


def main():
    play_game()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two typo mistakes in your code.

1. In `Food` class must be function `__init__` instead of `__int__`.
2. In `Food.__init__` in line `self.shapesize(stretch_len=0.5, stetch_wid=0.5)` in second param `stetch_wid` you lost `r`. it must be `stretch_wid`.

And now you can see the food.